# Getting Gmail Atom Feed with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to get Atom feed for an email account using HttpClient. Before I tried to get `mail.google.com` and use them with custom `HttpClientHandler` but it didn't work.

I've searched for solution and managed to find out that I can use `Authorization header to pass credentials to the server but this doesn't work either. Am I doing something wrong? Why am I gtting 401 error? Does this method no longer work?

Here's my code:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckMail()
{
    AMailRefresher.handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    string url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";
    var encoded = StringToByte64(user + ":" + password);
    HttpResponseMessage res = null;
    try
    {
        HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        res = await AMailRefresher.http.SendAsync(req);
    }
    catch { }
    var xml = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (lastFeedScan == null)
        lastFeedScan = xml;
    if (xml != lastFeedScan)
    {
        lastFeedScan = xml;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static string StringToByte64(string text)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enabled [2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) for your Google account (i.e. new logins send a code in a text message to your phone which you must then enter to authorize the login) then you cannot use your (base 64 encoded) normal password with this approach. Instead, you must create an App password in order to bypass the 2-Step Verification. See [Sign in using App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for detail. The **How to generate an App password** section directs you to [App passwords](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) where you can create a custom, unique 16 character password for your application to use instead.

Comment: Thanks, I already managed to get it to work though. I used OAuth2 or some such nonsense and after some time I managed to work this out.